# Annoying Windows Security Dialog, whats wpad.mydomain.com?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server which I moved to a new location last weekend. After configuring the DNS server (there is an Active directory installed as well) I get this dialog "Windows Security" every now and then, especially when trying to interface towards the Interwebs...

It has a message.

[image]

Connecting to wpad.domain.com

Now, any ideas what this is and how I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wpad.yourdomain.com is the internet explorer proxy autodetect.
You should be able to make it go away by turning proxy autodetection off in group policy.

http://perimetergrid.com/wp/2008/01/11/wpad-internet-explorers-worst-feature/

Comment: Thanks, a more specific place where to look? The Group Policy Management tool is a bitch when it comes to the ui :/